Citing two authors with "and" instead of & between two names
I'm trying to Cite two authors with 'and" instead of &, for example: lian and yuan (2021). But, I see Lian & yuan (2021) in text. Would you please help me? How can I cite to see "and" between two names, not"&"?

The solution here will depend on the style you are using. (And also on the bibliography/citation packages. Only the tagging suggests you use biblatex.) Please show us a small, compilable example document that reproduces the status quo with as little code as possible. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.
